# How can I view archived messages in Gmail but filter by category?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

I heavily rely on Gmail's category organization. Lately I've started archiving emails that I've looked at already to avoid clutter in my "primary" category.

However I've run into a problem. If I want to look at a recent "primary" email, I can go to `All Mail` and look through them, but then it's totally cluttered up with all the other emails.

Is there any way to go to `All Mail` and then filter by category? Or is this just not possible because the categorization is destroyed by the archiving operation?

What I've tried:

- If I click on `All Mail` I see all archived messages. If I then use `category:primary` in the search bar, it resets and only shows me the un-archived primary emails.
- I've reviewed Gmail's search operators (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), but could not find an appropriate entry.

Comment: what is the result if you go into your category and then you search `NOT label:inbox` ? or else `category:primary AND NOT label:inbox`

Comment: Thanks @boly38 for the response. `category:primary AND NOT label:inbox`  returns no results. But `NOT label:inbox` seems promising! I think it's doing what I wanted! If I search from my primary section of my inbox with `NOT label:inbox` it seems to include things that I've archived, but doesn't include spam/updates, etc. Thanks I think that's it! PS it's very curious to me that it doesn't work unless `NOT` is in all caps.

Comment: How did you think of that?!

Comment: @boly38 I've checked a few times and I think that's exactly the behavior I was describing. If you post that as an answer I think I can accept and call this one closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use `NOT label:inbox` to get entries that are non more in inbox (ex. archived entries)

it seems that google support [search operator page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en&visit_id=637600756829355811-3708116729&rd=1) just missed `NOT` keyword

Comment: Yea no kidding! And the fact that the `NOT` has to be in all caps is thoroughly baffling.